# Survival Analysis and multiple observations

Tags: survival, cox-model, biostatistics, epidemiology

I am currently conducting a survival analysis for the first time and I am finding the conceptual aspects of the analysis a bit tricky. I have a hospitalization dataset that spans over a 20 year period and includes all hospitalizations in the geographic area of study. Because of this some individuals are hospitalized multiple times. I am attempting to assess the association of diabetes with in-hospital death among patients hospitalized for a specific type of a salmonella infection, aka everyone in the dataset has this infection (I do not have any info on whether death occurred outside the hospital, I only know if an individual died in the hospital). Additionally I also have the length of stay of each hospitalization event, which I was planning to use as my time indicator. A vast majority of the patients in the dataset where only hospitalized once (around 94%), 5% have two hospitalizations, and 1% have more than 2 hospitalizations. I would like to keep these patients with multiple hospitalizations, as only around 2% of the sample had the event (in-hospital death) and of those deaths 17% were in patients hospitalized more than once.

I am wondering how I should handle these rehospitalized patients, since they are being censored and then later reentering the study and thus being observed again. Should the additional hospitalization start times begin at the stop time of the last hospitalization? Additionally, since the dataset contains no linkage ID and is organized with each row as a separate hospitalization event rather than each row being a patient, I had to use a matching algorithm to match patients with multiple hospitalizations based on other variables like age, race, sex etc. Is there anyway to account for this in the analysis or do I simply need to lay out this fact when describing the study and results?

I am planning to use a cox proportional hazards model.

Comment: Given the rareness of the event (hospitalisation with salmonella infection) and the (apparent) relative paucity of the data available for matching, how certain are you that the "double admissions" are in fact the same person?

Comment: As a follow-up comment (which I might expand into an answer) I suspect that you're best to essentially treat each hospitalisation as an independent event (given the supposed repeats are very rare).

Comment: Then each hospitalisation would effectively start anew at time=0, with subsequent in-hospital death estimated across all the rows (with censoring)

Comment: As a final comment (ahead of any potential future answer) it is possible to account for repeat risk-periods (which could be conceptualised as clustered data). See for example this CV answer: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/178022/16974 (the question asks a different point, but the answer talks about robust variance and frailty models which might apply in this case)

Comment: I am relatively certain they are the same individuals since their rehospitalizations are no more than a few months apart at worst and most (but not all) patients have a national ID to match on.