# Variable selection/ Classification time series binary outcome

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, classification, feature-selection

I have a dataset of subjects with a binary outcome (1=disease, 0=healthy), and a column with the time in which the levels of several biomarkers (continuous values) were measured at each time point for a given subject. 
The number of time points corresponds to the number of samples. For example, if I have 50 samples there are also 50-time points. There is a problem with p>>n. In fact, the number of predictors (biomarkers) is much higher than the number of samples (n). Finally, the samples of the two classes have a common time series (only one column). For example:

[image]

My questions are:

1) it is possible to build a classifier to distinguish the two classes and considering that the levels of biomarkers show decreasing or increasing trends with the time? I don’t want to build a model without taking into account the information of the time. Because as said, it is possible that there is a relation between time and level of biomarkers.

2) I would like to identify the most important variable derived from 1)

What is in your opinion the best model that can I use to analyze my data? I have found that could be useful approaches based on time series analysis (e.g. Arima) but I have also seen the application of machine learning approaches (e.g. random forest).

I am looking mainly for something that I can implement in R.

I am sorry If I have used some incorrect terms or I have explained not well some concepts. I really appreciate in advance any kind of support.

Comment: Do you have the outcome in time series form as well?

Comment: Hi thanks for the question. I have reported an example of my dataset in my post. I have simplified the questions for reason of explanation.  The classes and the time were obtained using other analysis and the output is this format.

Comment: OK. You might want to try treating it as a VAR model, and then after predicting the outcome variable, apply a decision threshold to insure a binary outcome. In theory for this type of problem you could use LSTM as binary time series classifier, but because you have so few samples, LSTM won't work well.

Comment: thanks! I will try to study VAR model to understand if it is suitable for my data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I am fully understanding you. I would have prefer to post as a comment, but I lack reputation to do so.
May be it would be clearer if you post a little bit of your data.

If I understand properly it is mixed effects cox regression? Are your data somehow like [data in this page (but you having much more columns)](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/dae/mixed-effects-cox-regression/)?

May be you want to check [answer and comments to this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/177175/survival-analysis-account-for-repeated-measures)

As you talk about biomarkers I imagine you are in live sciences, may be you want consider creating a categorical variable containing if some biomarker increases or decreases (appart from the outcome variable) and testing it against the outcome. For instance, person A has increased values of biomarker X over time and person B has stable values. May be it could be helpful -depending on your data- to create a variable called Xincreasing being 1 for person A and 0 for person B.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply and suggestions. I have edited my post with an example of the data. Hope that this could be useful.